# Return JSON Result as 1 to many Relationship Mysql query using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

1. word_table(word_id,word,meaning)
2. synonyms(s_id,synonym,word_id)
3. antonyms(a_id,antonym,word_id)

I have 3 tables. `word_table` contains words and meaning. `synonyms` table contains synonyms corresponding word_table using word_id as foreign key.
`antonyms` table contains Antonyms corresponding word_table using word_id as foreign Key

I would like to get a JSON result via PHP Mysql Result as follows

```
words
[{
  "word":"defy",
  "meaning":"challenge",
  "synonyms":[ "violate", "withstand", "ignore" ],
  "antonyms":[ "respect", "abet", "like" ]
},
"word":"defy",
"meaning":"challenge",
"synonyms":[ "violate", "withstand", "ignore" ],
"antonyms":[ "respect", "abet", "like" ]
},
"word":"defy",
"meaning":"challenge",
"synonyms":[ "violate", "withstand", "ignore" ],
"antonyms":[ "respect", "abet", "like" ]
}
]
```

Comment: paste your code.

Comment: Have you any code to share or would you like someone to write it all for you?

Comment: What about `json_encode`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$json_result = json_encode($result);
```

This is assuming that `$result` is the results of your query.